# Trying to add a keydown event to a function

Tags: javascript, onsubmit, onkeydown

I have been trying to add a keydown event to this function so that it not only submits the form when SUBMIT is clicked, but also when ENTER is pressed. My code and the code I want to add are below. I have tried to get the two to work together, but I'm confused about how to add the second code block. Oh, and validate() is being called from the HTML submit button element in the HTML file. Do I need to remove it from the HTML and create a brand new function that will perform both actions?

Can anyone help, please and thank you?

Here is my code:

```
function validate() {
  var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
  var password = document.getElementById("password").value;

  if (username == "abc" && password == "123") {
    window.location = "http://www.google.com"; 
    return false;
  } else {
    alert("The user name or password is invalid.");
  }
}
```

and here is the code I want to add:

```
function (event) {
    if (event.which == 13 || event.keyCode == 13) {
        //code to execute here
        return false;
    }
    return true;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should add event to body then validate it.

try this:

```
document.getElementById('body').addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
if (event.which == 13 || event.keyCode == 13) {
/* validate your form here and submit your form */
    document.forms[0].submit();
    return false;
}
return true;
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Ali. Your answer got my gears turning again and freed me to continue researching. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After some more research, I found this link http://jsfiddle.net/Jaganathan/6AWkH/2/ and from there, figured out a workable solution for what I needed.

The code I ended up using is below. I hope it will help someone else, too.

```js
$(function() {
   
   $('body').keypress(function(event) {
      var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
   var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
    if (event.which == 13) {
     if (username == "abc" && password == "123") {
      window.location = "/Sites/IRAnalystDay2015/homepage/index.htm"; //redirecting to other page
      return false;
     } else {
      alert(
       "The user name or password is invalid."
      );
     }
    }
   });
   
   $("#submit").click(function() {
      var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
   var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
    var e = jQuery.Event('keypress');
    e.which = 13; // #13 = Enter key
    if (username == "abc" && password == "123") {
     window.location = "/Sites/IRAnalystDay2015/homepage/index.htm"; //redirecting to other page
     return false;
    } else {
     alert("The user name or password is invalid.");
    }
   });
   
});
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Javascript Login Form Validation</title>

 <!-- include css file here-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>
 
 <!-- include javascript file here-->
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/login.js"></script> 
      
  </head>
  <body>
 <div class="container">
   <div class="main"> 
  <form id="form_id" method="post" name="myform">
    <label>User Name :</label></br>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username"/></br>
 
    <label>Password :</label></br>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password"/></br>
 
    <input type="button" value="Login" id="submit" />
  </form>
   </div>

 </div>
 </body>
</html>
```